# python regex matching between two wild characters

Tags: python, regex, file

I have a file that contains some lines with the following format.

```
...
...
ABC_DEF( ac, bad, dd, ..)
...
...
```

I want to grep for the ac and bad from the ABC_DEF and modify the file such that ..

```
...
...
ac, bad, 
ABC_DEF(dd, ...)
...
...
```

ac and bad are just examples, it will be alpha numeric characters with some size.

I have the following code in python

```
import re
for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1):
    line = re.sub(r'ABC_DEF\(\w+,\w+,', r'ABC_DEF(', line.rstrip())
    print(line)
```

But this does not seem to work. Can someone please help.

Thanks,

Comment: re.sub(r'ABC_DEF\(\s*\w+\s*,\s*\w+\s*,\s*', r'ABC_DEF(', line.rstrip()) seems to be working fine. I want to catch the ac and the bad and prepend those two words in the above line of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need

```
line = re.sub(r'ABC_DEF\(\s*\w+\s*,\s*\w+\s*,\s*', r'ABC_DEF(', line.rstrip())
```

because there could be spaces around the words.

```
>>> line = 'ABC_DEF(  first ,  second   , third, fourth)'
>>> line = re.sub(r'ABC_DEF\(\s*\w+\s*,\s*\w+\s*,\s*', 
r'ABC_DEF(', line.rstrip())
>>> line
'ABC_DEF(third, fourth)'
```

UPDATE: You asked in the comments that you wanted to know how to capture the values. You do this by putting parens on the parts you want to capture and then call `re.match` instead. Like this:

```
>>> line = 'ABC_DEF(  first ,  second   , third, fourth)'
>>> match = re.match(r'ABC_DEF\(\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*', line)
>>> match.group(1)
'first'
>>> match.group(2)
'second'
```

Comment: Thanks Ray.. Sorry . I could not upvote or mark it as correct answer.  I am new to this.

Comment: I have one more doubt .. is it possible to catch and store it in some variables .. like $1 = first and $2=second. ..

Comment: Added to the answer